# The Speaker icon is removed, while switching the route from Bluetooth or Microphone to Speaker from the call kit screen

Tags: react-native, callkit, ios-bluetooth, speaker, audio-route

I am using RNCallKeep and react-native-incall-manager to handle the audio routing from the application UI, during VOIP calls.
While switching the route from Bluetooth or Microphone to Speaker from the call kit screen, the Speaker icon is visible for a split second then it changes back to the previous route icon (Bluetooth / Microphone). However, the route stays on Speaker.

Although switching back to Bluetooth / Microphone works fine and the icon is also updated accordingly.

I am receiving the audio route change notification for "Speaker" in the following method in onAudioRouteChange method in RNCallKeep.m. Also, on the JS side, I am getting the Event as well as shown in bold in the below logs, however on the callkit screen the icon changes to Bluetooth again.

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Connect a Bluetooth headset to your iOS device
- Initiate or receive a VOIP call
- When the route is set to Bluetooth/Microphone
- Now switch the route to Speaker from the Callkit screen (issue is reproduced here)
- Now again switching the route to Microphone or Bluetooth works fine.

```
2024-01-25 18:13:08.970608+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.storeOriginalAudioSetup(): origAudioCategory=AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, origAudioMode=AVAudioSessionModeDefault
2024-01-25 18:13:08.974912+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startAudioSessionNotification() starting...
2024-01-25 18:13:08.975025+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startAudioSessionInterruptionNotification()
2024-01-25 18:13:08.975299+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification()
2024-01-25 18:13:08.975354+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLostNotification()
2024-01-25 18:13:08.975435+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification()
2024-01-25 18:13:08.975465+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification()
2024-01-25 18:13:08.975839+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.start:auto:ringbackUriType:: audioSession.setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: 0 success
2024-01-25 18:13:08.976143+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.start:auto:ringbackUriType:: audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat) success
2024-01-25 18:13:08.979351+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.start:auto:ringbackUriType:: audioSession.setActive(YES), withOptions: 0 success
2024-01-25 18:13:08.979435+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.startProximitySensor()
2024-01-25 18:13:08.979533+0530 [864:288247] RNInCallManager.setKeepScreenOn(): enable: YES

2024-01-25 18:13:09.614664+0530 [864:288020] [RNCallKeep][CXProviderDelegate][provider:didActivateAudioSession]
2024-01-25 18:13:09.614908+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioSessionInterruptionNotification: Ended
2024-01-25 18:13:09.614949+0530 [864:288020] [RNCallKeep][configureAudioSession] Activating audio session

2024-01-25 18:13:09.746392+0530 [864:288020] [RNCallKeep] sendEventWithNameWrapper: RNCallKeepDidActivateAudioSession, hasListeners : YES

2024-01-25 18:13:09.847646+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification: End
2024-01-25 18:13:09.878653+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Inside Event Listener RNCallKeep didChangeAudioRoute
2024-01-25 18:13:09.878762+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Receiver


2024-01-25 18:13:09.973877+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute(): did NOT overrideOutputAudioPort()
2024-01-25 18:13:09.985134+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute() did NOT change audio category
2024-01-25 18:13:09.985216+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute() did NOT change audio mode
2024-01-25 18:13:09.985249+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: End
2024-01-25 18:13:09.985276+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: Unknow Value


2024-01-25 18:13:11.843002+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.Reason: CategoryChange. category=AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode=AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat
2024-01-25 18:13:11.843219+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute(): [Enter] forceSpeakerOn flag=0 media=audio category=AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode=AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat
2024-01-25 18:13:11.844413+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute(): did NOT overrideOutputAudioPort()
2024-01-25 18:13:11.844540+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute() did NOT change audio category
2024-01-25 18:13:11.844576+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute() did NOT change audio mode
2024-01-25 18:13:11.844609+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: End
2024-01-25 18:13:11.844637+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: Unknow Value

2024-01-25 18:13:15.427909+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Printing Before Audio Routes in ComponenetDidMount iOS
2024-01-25 18:13:15.430607+0530 [864:288524] [RNCallKeep][getAudioRoutes]
2024-01-25 18:13:15.590945+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Printing Audio Routes in ComponenetDidMount iOS
2024-01-25 18:13:15.591650+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] [ { name: 'Speaker', type: 'Speaker' },
  { name: 'iPhone Microphone', selected: true, type: 'Phone' },
  { name: 'Rockerz 238 Pro', type: 'Bluetooth' } ]
2024-01-25 18:13:15.593427+0530 [864:288524] [RNCallKeep][getAudioRoutes]
2024-01-25 18:13:15.599402+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Audio Route SetTImeOut changed
2024-01-25 18:13:15.599523+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Getting route
2024-01-25 18:13:15.600062+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] [ { name: 'Speaker', type: 'Speaker' },
  { name: 'iPhone Microphone', selected: true, type: 'Phone' },
  { name: 'Rockerz 238 Pro', type: 'Bluetooth' } ]
2024-01-25 18:13:15.651189+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Bluetooth:AudioRoute
2024-01-25 18:13:15.750667+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] 'ChangeRoute: ios :: ', 'Bluetooth'
2024-01-25 18:13:15.750962+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] 'ChangeRoute: this.state.routeName: ', 'Rockerz 238 Pro'

2024-01-25 18:13:15.752629+0530 [864:288525] [RNCallKeep][setAudioRoute] - inputName: Rockerz 238 Pro

2024-01-25 18:13:16.123263+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.Reason: Override
2024-01-25 18:13:16.123347+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: End
2024-01-25 18:13:16.123375+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: Unknow Value
2024-01-25 18:13:16.180331+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Inside Event Listener RNCallKeep didChangeAudioRoute
2024-01-25 18:13:16.180445+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] BluetoothHFP
2024-01-25 18:13:20.651713+0530 [864:288633] [RNCallKeep][getAudioRoutes]
2024-01-25 18:13:20.759155+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Audio Route SetTImeOut changed
2024-01-25 18:13:20.759796+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Getting route
2024-01-25 18:13:20.761072+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] [ { name: 'Speaker', type: 'Speaker', selected: true },
  { name: 'iPhone Microphone', type: 'Phone' },
  { name: 'Rockerz 238 Pro', type: 'Bluetooth' } ]
2024-01-25 18:13:20.777916+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.Reason: Override
2024-01-25 18:13:20.778024+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: End
2024-01-25 18:13:20.778059+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: Unknow Value
2024-01-25 18:13:20.987289+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Inside Event Listener RNCallKeep didChangeAudioRoute
2024-01-25 18:13:20.987796+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Speaker
2024-01-25 18:13:22.546169+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Thu Jan 25 2024 18:13:22 GMT+0530 | sip.Transport | Sending WebSocket message:
2024-01-25 18:13:25.678314+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Inside Event Listener RNCallKeep didChangeAudioRoute
2024-01-25 18:13:25.678435+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Receiver
2024-01-25 18:13:25.679460+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.Reason: CategoryChange. category=AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode=AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat
2024-01-25 18:13:25.679736+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute(): [Enter] forceSpeakerOn flag=0 media=audio category=AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode=AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat
2024-01-25 18:13:25.680968+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute(): did NOT overrideOutputAudioPort()
2024-01-25 18:13:25.681411+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute() did NOT change audio category
2024-01-25 18:13:25.681478+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.updateAudioRoute() did NOT change audio mode
2024-01-25 18:13:25.681513+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: End
2024-01-25 18:13:25.681540+0530 [864:288020] RNInCallManager.AudioRouteChange.SilenceSecondaryAudioHint: Unknow Value
2024-01-25 18:13:25.993789+0530 [864:288525] [RNCallKeep][getAudioRoutes]
2024-01-25 18:13:26.002005+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Audio Route SetTImeOut changed
2024-01-25 18:13:26.002414+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] Getting route
2024-01-25 18:13:26.003373+0530 [864:288249] [javascript] [ { name: 'Speaker', type: 'Speaker' },
  { name: 'iPhone Microphone', selected: true, type: 'Phone' },
  { name: 'Rockerz 238 Pro', type: 'Bluetooth' } ]
```